# Avoiding C# JIT overhead

Tags: c#, jit

Is there an easy way of JIT-ing C# code up front, rather than waiting for the first time the code is invoked?  I have read about NGEN but I don't think that's going to help me.

My application waits and responds to a specific external event that comes from a UDP port, and  none of the critical-path code is (a) run before the event arrives, or (b) ever run again, so the cost of JIT is high in this scenario.  Checking with ANTS profiler the overhead for JIT is around 40-50%, sometimes it's as high as 90%.  My application is highly latency sensitive, and every millisecond counts.

My initial thought is that I could add a bool parameter to every critical path method, and call those methods before the event occurs, in order to initiate the JIT compile.  However, is there a prettier and less hacky way?

Many thanks

Comment: Why wouldn't NGEN help you?

Comment: Have you determined that it _is_ a problem? Or do you merely think it might be?

Comment: I'm (virtually) certain it's the problem Henk.  I just implemented on a single method my hacky approach and the JIT overhead for that method in ANTS profiler has disappeared.

Comment: NGEN is the way to go. Just run it via your installer/script when you deploy and forget about any IL compilation overhead at runtime.

Comment: John: I have tried running NGEN install <myapp.exe> and can see the images being compiled, but I'm still getting the same performance problem according to my Stopwatch measurements.

Comment: You app is just one large exe?

Comment: No, it's an exe with a series of DLLs, but running NGEN on the exe appears to run NGEN on all of its dependencies...or perhaps I've misinterpreted the output?

Comment: Random question: is there any way that while you are *waiting*, you could send a spoof message through the system, just redirecting any side-effects? so you can prime the code without actually doing anything? just a thought

Comment: That is a possibility Marc, especially if NGEN is not going to help me and there is no canonical way to solve this problem.

Comment: I agree with @MarcGravell. Perform a dry run of the code and substitute any dependencies that cause undesirable side effects with mocks.

Comment: I added some metrics to my pre-JIT method on a small application. If `PrepareMethod` was indeed JITting all the methods I passed in, it is mighty fast. Release build yield **231ms** for 17,553 methods passed in (included GAC assemblies).

Attached debug mode yielded a result of **840ms** for 46,034 methods passed to `PrepareMethod`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd say use NGEN and if it doesn't work, you likely have deeper problems.

But, to answer your question, this article on how to [pre-jit](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/pre_JIT.aspx) uses `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.PrepareMethod` to force a JIT.  It includes sample code to use reflection to get the method handles.

Comment: Excellent, thanks.  I have also found a CodeProject(!) article that wraps up PrepareMethod calls for entire types.  Link here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/Jitting.aspx.

Answer (score 3):

What happens the second time the event arrives? Is it faster then or just as slow. If its still slow then JIT is not the problem, because the code gets "JIT"ed only once, the first time it is run.

NGEN would provide the answer for you. My suggestion is to take the bare minimum of the code you need, the critical path if you will, and put it in dummy/sandbox project. Start profiling/NGenning this code and seeing the performance.

If this bare minimum code, even after being NGEN'ed performs poorly on multiple calls, then pre-compiling isn't going to help you. Its something else in the code that is causing performance bottle necks.

Comment: The code is lightning fast after the first event.  As I mentioned above, I've identified that it's definitely JIT overhead that's causing the performance issues.  I am in the process of adding a load of calls to RuntimeHelpers.PrepareMethod, hopefully that will remove this issue.